# Find the label for a selected checkbox button control using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, checkbox

this is my code, how I can retrieve the list of label checkbox checked

```
    for( var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++  )            //Remplir tableau liste des identifiants étapes
        { 
            $('#lbtn2').append("<input name='op' checked type='checkbox' value="+results.rows.item(i).Phrase+"    id="+results.rows.item(i).idPhrase+" />");
            $('#lbtn2').append('<label for='+results.rows.item(i).idPhrase+'>'+results.rows.item(i).Phrase+'</label>');
        }

        $('#lbtn2').append('<a href="#'+window.localStorage.getItem("id_grp")+'"  class="ba2"   data-role="button" >ajouter</a>').trigger('create');



$('.ba2').live('click', function () 
{
//Code for recover list of checkbox chechked
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.ba2').live('click', function(){
    $("#lbtn2 input[type='checkbox'] :selected").each(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var list = $(":checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ba2').live('click', function () 
{
 $("#lbtn2 input:radio:checked'").each(function(index){
      alert(this).val());
});
```

}

remember to use checked="checked" for valid markup.

Comment: the Behavior that make me the first word of appreciation for what is against sentence